# ordering by total number of rows

Tags: sql

Here is my scenario,
"movies" table on the mysql database,

```
director_id     movie
-----------     ------
1                movie1
1                movie2
1                movie3
3                movie4
3                movie5
2                movie6
2                movie7
2                movie8
2                movie9
```

how can i order directors by number of the movies they have as descending ?

Like this

2  -> 4 movies

1  -> 3 movies

3   -> 2 mvoies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT director_id, COUNT(*) as TotalMovies FROM movies
  GROUP BY director_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a calculated column based on the count of the records for each Director, and order on that.

ie
    SELECT Directors, count(DISTINCT directors) FROM movies GROUP BY directors;